# How to add color automatically when the radio button is already clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

This is my current svg chart

[image]

This is I want If the radio button is clicked the box will be automatically filled by black.

[image]

This is my svg code for box

```
<svg class="teeth" id="svg" 
 width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <!-- upper right 8 -->
    <g id="premolar-group">
        <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
        <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />

<input type="radio" name="browser" value="Y" id="answer">


    </g>

</svg>
```

Can anyone help how to fill out the box by color black when the radio button is already clicked?

Comment: I don't think you can put an `input` in an SVG like that.

Comment: So @Paulie_D that the input is will be on the outside of SVG?

Comment: you can use javascript to  add  an event listener to your button and if it is checked you can change color  of your svg by changing `fill="white"` to  a different color.

Comment: The more common way to do this is by place the input before the SVG in the HTML, then use `:checked +` to style the svg. eg. https://jsfiddle.net/mjxnLdqz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to get the elements in the SVG that you want to update. In your case, it looks like your after all `polygon`s and `rect` elements.

Once you have that, you can use the `fill` property to color the elements.

```js
const radioButton = document.getElementById('answer');
radioButton.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target.value === 'Y') {
    const polygons = document.querySelectorAll('svg polygon, svg rect');
    polygons.forEach(p => p.setAttribute('fill', 'red') );
  }
});
```

```html
<svg class="teeth" id="svg" width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <!-- upper right 8 -->
    <g id="premolar-group">
        <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
        <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />


    </g>

</svg>
<input type="radio" name="browser" value="Y" id="answer">
```

As mentioned in the comments, you need to put your input element outside of the SVG. If you want it in the center, you'll have to do some absolute positioning to make that happen.

Additionally, you can do this without JavaScript by using the `:checked` selector. However, if you do this, you will need to move your `input` element above your SVG (unless you're using scss, you can change up the selector).

Example:

```css
input:checked + svg rect,
input:checked + svg polygon {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="browser" value="Y" id="answer">

<svg class="teeth" id="svg" width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <!-- upper right 8 -->
    <g id="premolar-group">
        <rect x="75" y="75" stroke="black" id="occlusal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" width="150" height="150" fill="white"/>
        <polygon stroke="black" id="buccal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 0 300 0 225 75 75 75" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="mesial" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 0 300 300 225 225 225 75" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="palatal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="300 300 0 300 75 225 225 225" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" id="distal" style="stroke-width: 5px;" points="0 300 0 0 75 75 75 225" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross1" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />
        <polygon stroke="black" class="distal cross2" style="stroke-width: 5px;" fill="white" />


    </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: You could do this without any JavaScript if you just rearrange the elements https://jsfiddle.net/mjxnLdqz/

Comment: True. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: sir @mwhilson if I clicked the radio button my all SVG chart is already filled out by color red I have 32 charts. sir can you re-edit your answer based on the id of one SVG chart please I'm just a student and trying to understand about SVG and javascript

Comment: I have 13 reputation only. I can only do is accept the answer

Comment: So you want your svg to have a different color than red? What color do you want?

Comment: this line I want to change document.querySelectorAll('svg polygon, svg rect'); because this line scope all SVG in my table I have 32 SVG chart I want is only one chart filled out by red

Comment: I changed this to this  document.querySelectorAll('svg#svg g'); but it didn't work